# Generating wrapper code for a c++ library to be used in python

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, swig

I am creating a simulation tool in python and require a c++ library. How do I go about interfacing the library with python? The library is large but I only want to call a few functions and class member functions.

So far I have tired using ctypes and SWIG on smaller bits of c++ code just to familiarize myself with the process.

With ctypes the c++ library must already be compiled into a shared library, which is not a problem. I have used ctypes to call c++ function from a shared library but can you use ctypes to call class member functions?

If I use SWIG must I include all the header files of the c++ library in the interface file or only the ones that include the function I need?

Comment: depending on how polished you want things, Cython makes it pretty easy to wrap things as well.  there's also a Jupyter notebook module that makes interactive testing/development really convenient

Comment: @SamMason can Cython be used to wrap c++ code from an existing library?

Comment: yup, and there are lots of Q&As here about that try googling for "cython c++"!  https://dmtn-013.lsst.io/ also looks useful.  details depend a lot on what you're trying to expose/share between the languages, easiest is just calling a few functions and passing native datatypes and you can make things arbitrarily complicated

Answer (score 0):

`ctypes` can call C interfaces, or C++ interfaces that are `extern "C"`, but it does not understand C++-specific classes such as `std::string` or member functions.

With SWIG, you may include only the headers in the SWIG interface file that you want to expose to Python.  For example:

```
%module example

%{  
// This section is copied into the wrapper so the generated code can compile.
// No wrappers are generated from this.
#include "myheader1.h"
#include "myheader2.h"
%}

%include "myheader1.h"  // Wrap all functions directly declared in this header.    
int myfunc(int a, int b);  // Wrap only this one function in myheader2.h.
```

Comment: so if for example I only want to use a single function from a library but that function relies on other functions and classes within the library then I should include all headers between %{ %} and then wrap only the single function required below?

Comment: @tristan yes, at a minimum.